# Center geom_text on ggplot while controlling bar width

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a horizontal bar chart in `ggplot2` where the bars are of equal width and with text labels centered on the bars. There are two groups on the y axis -- one with 2 bars, and one with three.

There are a lot of similar questions on SO that address both of these issues, but I haven't been able to fix one without breaking the other. Here's my data:

```
## data 
df <- tibble(var1 = c("a", "b", "b", "c", "c"), 
             var2 = c("x", "y", "x", "y", "x"),
             proportion = c(100, 33.3, 66.7, 66.7, 33.3)) %>%
    mutate(var1 = factor(var1, levels = var1_order))

var1_order <- c("a", "c", "b")
```

Here's an example where the widths are good, but the labels of the y group are off:

```
## labels bad
df %>%  
    ggplot(aes(x = proportion, y = var2, fill = var1, 
               label = paste0(round(proportion, 1), "%"))) +
        geom_col(position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single", padding = 0), width = .9) +    
        geom_text(size = 3, position = position_dodge2(width = 0.9), hjust = -.5,
                  color = "black", aes(group = var1)) +  
        scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("#093D6E","#5D8AA8", "#00918B", 
                                                "#F8AF54",   "#CD9575")) +
        labs(x = NULL) +
        theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
              axis.title.y = element_blank(),
              axis.line=element_blank(),
              axis.text.x = element_blank(),
              panel.background = element_blank(),
              strip.text = element_text(size = 7, face = "bold")) + 
              scale_x_continuous(expand = c(.2, .2)) +
        guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```

And here's an example where the labels are good but the widths are now off:

```
## col widths bad

df %>%  
    ggplot(aes(x = proportion, y = var2, fill = var1, 
               label = paste0(round(proportion, 1), "%"))) +
        geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +    
        geom_text(size = 3, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), hjust = -.5,
                  color = "black", aes(group = var1)) +  
        scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("#093D6E","#5D8AA8", "#00918B", 
                                                "#F8AF54",   "#CD9575")) +
        labs(x = NULL) +
        theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
              axis.title.y = element_blank(),
              axis.line=element_blank(),
              axis.text.x = element_blank(),
              panel.background = element_blank(),
              strip.text = element_text(size = 7, face = "bold")) + 
              scale_x_continuous(expand = c(.2, .2)) +
        guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```

Note that this will be part of a parameterized report, so it needs to be capable of dealing with different numbers of var1 and var2 groups. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach. You can use `position_dodge2()` to keep uniform bars. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
df %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x = proportion, y = var2, fill = var1, 
             label = paste0(round(proportion, 1), "%"))) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(preserve = 'single',width = 0.9)) +    
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_dodge2(preserve = 'single',width = 0.9), hjust = -.5,
            color = "black", aes(group = var1)) +  
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("#093D6E","#5D8AA8", "#00918B", 
                                          "#F8AF54",   "#CD9575")) +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 7, face = "bold")) + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(.2, .2)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```

Output:

[image]